# auto variables with the same name in different C blocks: memory allocation

Tags: c, variables, scope, automatic-storage

Assume I have a structure like this in a C program:

```
if (res == NULL)
{
    int i = 1;
    ...
}
else
{
    int i = 2;
    ...
}
```

Will I save some amount of memory if I instead write

```
int i;

if (res == NULL)
{
    i = 1;
    ...
}
else
{
    i = 2;
    ...
}
```

?

The variable `i` is not needed outside the if-else structure.

Comment: That depends on the optimisation level and cannot be predicated across compiler implementations. At a guess: No. (This assumes that in your incomplete shown code, the spearate `int i;` is still on function level, not global. If it is global I'd guess that you waste instead of save memory.

Comment: @Yunnosch, what if the names were different?

Comment: By the way, please define what you mean by "memory". Stack? Total code size? Static RAM memory? ...

Comment: That would be as depending as with same names. Let me just refer you to Vlads answer. It provides the right way of thinking about this. Erics answer is closer to what you want to know, but I recommend Vlads way of thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No compiler of even modest quality will generate better code for either case than the other unless, possibly, its optimization features are disabled.

Comment: Even if the names are different?

Comment: @apadana: Even if the names are different. [Data-flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis) of where values are created and used is a standard part of optimization, and the lifetimes of the values in the sample code are identical regardless of name.

Comment: So I guess if one of the `i`s is a `char` and the other one is a `double`, the compiler will allocate the size of one double on the stack.

Comment: @apadana: In fairly simple code, they will not be on the stack at all; the compiler will get all the work done using registers only. (And, in many processors, `double` values are kept in different registers than `char` values, so it would be necessary to use different registers for them.) If it does become necessary to use the stack, because there is too much going on in a piece of code to hold everything in registers, the compiler should “spill” data to the stack intelligently. A given variable may not have a single reserved place on the stack; the compiler will use what it needs when needed.

Comment: @apadana: So a particular place on the stack might be used for variable `i` at one point in the program and for variable `j` at another. And `i` might be temporarily on the stack on one place at one point in the program but at a different place at another point in the program. This is generally true unless you take the address of a variable and, for example, pass it to another routine. Then the compiler must reserve a spot just for that variable, since it has to have a fixed address. Otherwise, the compiler is free to move things around.

Comment: @apadana: This is a good time to learn that C source code does not specify a sequence of operations that the compiler must perform in a strict way. It specifies an abstract computation, and the compiler analyzes the source code, generates a representation of that computation, and then attempts to figure out a good way to implement instructions that get the required results, even if the end result looks very different from the original source code.

Answer (score 2):

Do not bother about memory.

The code snippets have different semantics.

In the first code snippet the (two different) variables `i` are visible only within if and else statements.
So they can not be accessed outside the if statement.

In the second code snippet the variable i visible and alive outside the if statement. If it should be used only within the if statement then it is a bad programming style to declare a variable in a block where it is not used.